# How to calculate snubber for switched inductor?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, powermosfet, snubber

I'm driving inductive load with PWM and my MOSFET can not handle hard switching without reduce dv/dt ramp between drain-source. So I need to add RDC (resistor-diode-capacitor) snubber, but I don't know how to calculate propper values for it. Could you explain the calculation methodology to me, for snubber parallel to coil L1 and snubber parallel to MOSFET Q1? My load is about 12V and 1A of countinous DC (peak current is probably much higher :D ).

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: No I haven't. But it is good idea. :D

Comment: Can you pick a different FET?  12V @1A is easy for most modern FETs.  Just choose a 50V or higher and you're good with just the D1.

Comment: If you have to use this FET, simulation will get you close, but then layout parasitics will move it a bit, so you'll have to tune the board on the actual layout.

Comment: I have tried switching coil without MOSFET protection and always burns it out. I use IRF540 and it's maximum rating is 100V and 33A.

Comment: If you're burning up a 100V FET on a 12V boost converter there's something terribly wrong.  The FET might ring above 12V a bit due to parasitic inductance, but if it's reaching well over 100V you need to solve that problem first, and the answer is not adding a snubber.  A 12V 12W boost converter shouldn't even need a snubber.

Comment: What's your layout like?  Do you have a controller that regulates the output voltage at 12V, and have you checked to see that the output is not running away?

Comment: A custom tuned snubber only reduces over-shoot and under-shoot by about 3 dB. Any more reduction and the snubber starts to waste energy.

Comment: Please show your layout and oscillograms.